# When does the Tactical Officer trigger?

Tags: the-captain-is-dead

Does the tactical officer skill trigger off of other people repairing the shields or just when she repairs it?

Comment: This is hopefully something answered in the rulebook. I have not played this game, but I'd assume that this question has all the information it needs to answer.

Comment: @ryanyuyu The details of the card in question should be included in the question. It is useful to have more then a single sentence for a question.

Answer (score 1):

Tactical officer reads : "After repairing the shields, may draw 2 random skills from the skill deck."

It is my understanding that this wording is in reference to himself only. If they had intended it to be after anyone repairing shields, they would have explicitly called that out:

such as "After anyone repairs the shields ... "

[image: Card wording]